# echo PHP variable into JS parentheses

Tags: javascript, web

In my loop I have a link that sends the ID via a query string, however I want to do it through AJAX. I've attempted to do this through setting the PHP variable to a JS variable and haven't had much success. Everything I try says illegal token.

(It's on the 8th line).

```
<?php
//We display the list of read messages
while($dn2 = mysql_fetch_array($req2))
{
?>

        <tr>
        <td class="left"><a href="#" onclick="hello('"<?php echo $dn1['id']; ?>"')"><?php echo htmlentities($dn2['title'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></a></td>
        <td><?php echo $dn2['reps']-1; ?></td>
        <td><a href="profile.php?id='.<?php echo $dn2['userid']; ?>'."><?php echo htmlentities($dn2['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></a></td>
        <td><?php echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s' ,$dn2['timestamp']); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have way to many quotes going on here. I've cleaned it up below.

```
<?php
//We display the list of read messages
while($dn2 = mysql_fetch_array($req2))
{
?>
        <tr>
        <td class="left"><a href="#" onclick="hello('<?php echo $dn1['id']; ?>')"><?php echo htmlentities($dn2['title'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></a></td>
        <td><?php echo $dn2['reps']-1; ?></td>
        <td><a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $dn2['userid']; ?>"><?php echo htmlentities($dn2['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></a></td>
        <td><?php echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s' ,$dn2['timestamp']); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have too many quotes. Combining `"'` will cause you problems.

```
<td class="left"><a href="#" onclick="hello('<?php echo $dn1['id']; ?>')"><?php echo htmlentities($dn2['title'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a typo:
you are writing `$dn1['id']` instead of `$dn2['id']`
But that could be another problem. As others have pointed out, the problem seems to be your use of quotes.

Comment: there's another loop which defines $dn1, however I didn't think it was relevant but can see why you can see it would be an issue!

Comment: Edit: fixed. It was a typo!

Answer (score 0):

Where is $dn1 coming from? I only see $dn2

Comment: there's another loop which defines $dn1, however I didn't think it was relevant but can see why you can see it would be an issue!

Comment: Edit: fixed. It was a typo! My bad.